# jupyterhub - NLTK - unable to use stopwords

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, nltk, stop-words, jupyterhub

I am using below code to use stopwords through jupyter notebook. I have hosted jupyter on Linux server and using the notebook.

```
python3 -m nltk.downloader stopwords
python3 -m nltk.downloader words
python3 -m nltk.downloader punkt

python3
>>>from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>>stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
>>>print(stop_words)
```

This works fine while running in python terminal, but when I try below in Jupyternotebook its failing with error.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
print(stop_words)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py in __load(self)
     82                 try:
---> 83                     root = nltk.data.find("{}/{}".format(self.subdir, zip_name))
     84                 except LookupError:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/data.py in find(resource_name, paths)
    582     resource_not_found = "\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (sep, msg, sep)
--> 583     raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
    584 

LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource stopwords not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
```

When i try to download in python3 terminal I see its already upto date.

```
>>> import nltk >>> nltk.download('stopwords') [nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /root/nltk_data... [nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
```

But when tried through jupyter hub download is timing out. Ideally download is not required if its up to date. So is there is configuration in jupyter hub to handle this

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. I had downloaded `nltk packages` as root. But in Jupyter hub I was using as user.
Downloaded the package as user from python3 terminal on server and was able to fix this issue.

Thanks.